# md-is-error not working on md-input-container with md-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I use md-is-error to show error. It works fine in input but not working in md-select. This is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="inputdemoErrors" ng-app="MyApp">

  <md-content layout-padding="">
    <form ng-submit="projectForm()" name="testForm">

      <div layout="row">
       <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm md-is-error="project.postalCode == undefined && testForm.$submited">
            <label>Postal Code</label>
            <input ng-model="project.postalCode"
                   required name="ptCodeInput">
          </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container flex="50" md-is-error="project.type == undefined && testForm.$submited">
          <label>Project Type</label>
          <md-select ng-model="project.type" required>
            <md-option value="app">Application</md-option>
            <md-option value="web">Website</md-option>
          </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
      <div>
        <md-button type="submit">Submit</md-button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

My code works fine with `Postal Code`, but `Project Type` selection it not working.

Have any suggestion for use md-is-error in md-select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an issue raised for the same

**[md-select is missing md-input-invalid](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7255)**

It shows the error message when there is a change such as **`ng-blur`**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @JohnH No you cannot

Comment: OK Thanks so much @Sajeetharan